# systemd: How can I make shutdown wait until my oneshot service has finished running?

Tags: systemd

I have an issue with the standard unit file: `systemd-coredump@.service`.

If the system enters shutdown, I found that it always kills the service before completion - so the coredump file is missing. The question could apply to any critical service, I think.

`systemd-coredump@.service` is a oneshot service triggered by `systemd-coredump.socket`, which requires `var.mount` and (by default) resides inside `system-systemd@coredump.slice`.

I can somewhat stop this by removing `Conflicts=shutdown.target` rule set in the service, the slice, the socket and the mount. It doesn't delay the shutdown, and I need a `Conflicts=shutdown.target` on the mount, the slice and the socket. I want all these things to get terminated in the end... just after the coredump service completes naturally.

Is there a way to make systemd delay the `shutdown.target` rather than killing my critical task? Also it would be nice to have the normal timeout in case the service gets stuck.